# how to find the signal strength and mac address of the connected access point to which my device is connected at run time, programatically?

Tags: java, networking, wireless, bssid

Im trying to identify the access point to which my device is connected and the signal strength of the connection. 
If you could suggest some libraries in java it would help a lot.

FYI 
I looked around and found Access point class java doc      http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/accesspoint-3.3/com/oracle/mobile/io/accesspoint/package-summary.html

but couldn't find jar file to download.

If there is any other way in java ,suggestions are always welcomed (and this case needed :P )

Comment: What kind of device are you talking about? Android, Java ME, full Java SE?

Comment: Currently Im working with Java SE (for laptop's) later i will work on android too

Comment: I would like to write a cross functional code , hence choose java 
At the moment I have access to mac os (Yosemite) and windows 8.1.

Also where can I get the jar file wrt to doc I mentioned in the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the RSSI does not traverse beyond the device driver (unless you use libpcap or a similar lib to capture in user-space). Moreover, not all chips/drivers pass the RSSI to the Kernel.

So, either capture some packets or (depending on your chip/driver) write a small Kernel module that captures the RSSI.